# modify log messages sent to node inspectors

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools

Is it to possible intercept and modify messages/websockets (`console.log/error` calls) sent to connected node inspector (i.e. chrome's devTools)?

Idea is to log more stuff to node inspectors, as opposed to logging bare bones messages to basic tty. Also, devTools doesn't support tty color escape codes (as from e.g. `chalk` package), and vice versa tty doesn't support devTools' `console.log('%c', 'color: red')` styles.

Alternatively, is it possible to list websocket clients connected to current node process to see if a devTools inspector is connected, and thus assume we're debugging using *that*, so we can log differently? `http://localhost:9229/json/list` isn't much useful (if it was supposed to be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can leverage the fact that `console.log/error` uses `process.stdout` to write to terminal. So if we want to send a message only to an inspector, and not write it to terminal, we can temporarily disable `stdout` by overriding it:

```
// inspector-only loggers
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

const _stdoutWrite = process.stdout.write;
const _stderrWrite = process.stderr.write;

console.inspector = {};

[ "log", "warn", "error", "info" ].forEach( method => {

    const origLogger = console[method].bind( console );

    console.inspector[method] = ( ...args ) => {

        process.stdout.write = () => {};
        process.stderr.write = () => {};
        origLogger( ...args );
        process.stdout.write = _stdoutWrite;
        process.stderr.write = _stderrWrite;
    };    
});
```

Similarly, if we want to only log to terminal without logging to inspector, we can use `process.stdout` directly:

```
// terminal-only logger
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

console.tty = ( ...args ) => {
    args = args.reduce((a, b) => String(a) + " " + String(b), "" ).trim();
    process.stdout.write( args + "\n" );
}
```